# не работает код с TitaniumWeb Proxy

Tags: c#, веб-сервер, proxy

Писал код для редиректа в браузере, но браузеры выдают такую ошибку, хотя я даже делал валидацию сертификата в коде
вот код:

```
        public static ProxyServer proxyServer = new ProxyServer();
    public static void Start()
    {

            //proxyServer.CertificateManager.TrustRootCertificate(true);
            proxyServer.CertificateManager.CertificateEngine = CertificateEngine.BouncyCastle;
            var endpoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8080, true);
            proxyServer.AddEndPoint(endpoint);
            proxyServer.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += OnCertificateValidation;
            proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnRequest;
            //proxyServer.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback -= OnCertificateSelection;
            proxyServer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("СЕРВЕР ЗАПУСТИЛИ!");

    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        proxyServer.BeforeRequest -= OnRequest;
        proxyServer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("СТОПАНУЛ СЕРВАК!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }

    private static async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Зашли в редирект");
        Console.WriteLine(e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.Host.ToString());
        var host = e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.Host.ToLower();
        var host_ip = e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUriString.ToLower();
        Console.WriteLine(host);
        Console.WriteLine(host_ip);

        if (e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri.Host.ToString().Contains("vk.com"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Редиректаем на ЮТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТТ");
            e.Redirect("https://youtube.com/");
            Console.WriteLine("РЕДИРЕКТНУЛИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИИ");
        }

    }


    
    //static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    private static Task OnCertificateValidation(object sender, CertificateValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        // игнорирование некоторых ошибок SSL-сертификата
        if (e.SslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            e.IsValid = true;
        }

        if (e.SslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
        {
            foreach (X509ChainStatus chainStatus in e.Chain.ChainStatus)
            {
                if (chainStatus.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown &&
                    chainStatus.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                {
                    e.IsValid = false;
                }
            }

            e.IsValid = true;
        }

        //return false;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: насколько я понимаю, надо как-то добавить сертификат, сгенерированный TitaniumWeb Proxy, в доверенные сертификаты, но я не знаю, как сделать это программно и надо ли это делать. До этого, когда я первый раз запускал программу, у меня вылезло уведомление о новом сертификаты, и можно ли ему доверять. Но теперь, когда я запускаю прогу, ничего такого не вылазит